# Apply ColorFilter to bitmap using brush strokes

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I wanted to apply gray scale effect to a bitmap using brush strokes, i.e. user can use brush to apply gray scale effect to particlar area of bitmap as shown below:

[image: Gray scale effect with strokes]

I displayed bitmap on a view using canvas.drawBitmap(...) method. I learnt to draw brush strokes on bitmap using path and paint instances, I just want  to apply Gray Scale effect to bitmap on which brush strokes are drawn.

my Paint object is defined as :

```
Paint paint = new Paint();

paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setStyle(this.paintStyle);
paint.setStrokeWidth(this.paintStrokeWidth);
paint.setStrokeCap(this.lineCap);
paint.setDither(true);
paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER); 

ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
colorMatrix.setSaturation(0);

paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix));
paint.setAlpha(255);
```

But it doesn't draw any strokes. If I remove  paint.setColorFilter(...) and instead use paint.setColor(...), then i can see strokes on bitmap.
 I tried using paint.setXferMode(...) but it didnt work.

In my view's onDraw() i used

```
 canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Can somebody please point me to the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: set a `BitmapShader` to your `paint` object

Comment: @pskink : thanks! it worked !! You can answer the question so that I can mark it as accepted.